# openGL Tessellation problems

Tags: opengl, tessellation

[image: ??]

I'm trying to tesselate the teapot, the tesselation works fine inside these triangles that appear, but the model is not working.

The tesselation shaders and vertex shaders are the same used on this website.
http://prideout.net/blog/?p=48

The only exception is that transforming the vertexes is done in the vertex shader.

Has this ever happened with anyone here?
Would it be that the other vertexes don't form triangles?

The model is loaded from an obj file.

Comment: how do you setup the patch control points?

Comment: glPatchParameteri(GL_PATCH_VERTICES, patchVal); - everytime before drawing. I have keyboard controls for patchVal